# Which characters can I safely insert into an SQL database without escaping?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've had a look on Google to try and find out which characters are safe to insert into a MySQL database, but every time someone just seems to say "it's fine as long as you use `*_real_escape_string`

I'm trying to find out which different special characters I can use to generate a salt, so escaping characters will be no good since the salt column is limited to `char(10)`

The salt is automatically generated. Am I correct in thinking anything except the following characters are okay?

- '
- "
- \

Comment: `"` is okay actually. Just use `'` for string literals delimiter exclusively.

Comment: If you salt your characters before entering (it) in DB, they will be part of the salt and not the characters themselves being entered in DB. I don't foresee any issues with that. Once it's hashed, it can't be used against you.

Comment: INSERT INTO example (salt) VALUES ('\'\\"abc\'\\\\"') will working fine as @Fred-ii- said. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5fbfc/1)

Comment: (Addendum to my [`first`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172636/which-characters-can-i-safely-insert-into-an-sql-database-without-escaping#comment39193748_25172636) comment): with or without prepared statements. Hashes are "one way", providing you **are** hashing and not just salting, which the salt should be part of the hash, then entered in DB "after" it's been properly hashed.

Comment: I am generating a salt, then using it with the user's entered password to generate a sha512 hash, then inserting salt and hashed password into the DB. the problem is I use mysqli_query() with single quotes for the statment, and double quotes for values, so I don't think I can use `' or "` but I will definitely look into prepared statments.

Comment: What's your version of PHP? @cantsay

Comment: @cantsay It's a wise decision to switch to prepared statements, see the answer and the comments to the answer of zerkms.

Comment: @Fred-ii- PHP Version 5.4.4-14+deb7u12

Comment: Have a look at the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat), you might like that better. Yet, it's too bad you didn't have 5.5 you could've used the [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function right out of the box; there's no mussin' with seperate salts. @cantsay - Along with prepared statements; you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never ask such a question actually.

You **must** always use prepared statements/placeholders and not care of the actual characters.

Comment: I agree, best to handle all data the same rather than work around certain exceptions.

Comment: @EternalHour: that's well said